# Implementing a Dynamic "Lookup Criteria" for a Column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheet, I list dropdown options in a column. I get the options of this dropdown from a certain range in the other sheet.
[Data validation for single cell(g2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsYKW.jpg)
As you can see in the example, my data validation lookup criterion for the G2 cell is F133 to F260 in the "Lookup" Sheet.

What I want here is to get this data from the next column in the Lookup sheet in each cell that continues as G3-G4-G5.... For instance:  "G133-G260" for G3, "H133-H260" for G4.

I can do this manually one by one with creating a individual data validation per cell, but is there a quick way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create the data validation rules into the cells "G3:G" of the target sheet.
- The data validation rules use the range of `Lookup!F133:F260`, `Lookup!G133:G260`, `Lookup!H133:H260`,,, to "G2", "G3", "G4",,, of the target sheet, respectively.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set your target sheet name. And, save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your target sheet name.

  let offset = 6;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const loopupSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lookup");
  const range = sheet.getRange("G2:G" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const dataValidations = range.getValues().map(_ => [SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(loopupSheet.getRange(133, offset++, 128)).build()]);
  range.setDataValidations(dataValidations);
}
```

- When this script is run, the ranges of `Lookup!F133:F260`, `Lookup!G133:G260`, `Lookup!H133:H260`,,, are used as the data validation rules, and they are put to the cells "G2", "G3", "G4",,,.
- In this case, `sheet.getRange("G2:G" + sheet.getLastRow())` is used as the destination range. If you want to manually set the range, please modify it with like `sheet.getRange("G2:G10")`.
- `let offset = 6;` means that the 1st column is column "F". If you want to change this, please modify it.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setDataValidations(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without script if you're willing to have an auxiliary sheet. Just put in your Auxiliary sheet: `=TRANSPOSE(Lookup!G133:260)`

Then, go back and select your range in column G. Select all the cells and put in Data Validation from a Range: `=Auxiliary!1:1` - Be sure you don't put any "$", that way each cell will go and look in the next row and so on